# stable hashcode for IStructuralEquatable object

Tags: .net, hashcode, structural-equality

I need to build a stable (= does not vary with time) hashcode of an object.
Specifically, I do not know the exact type of the object. The only assumption I make is that it inherit from IStructuralEquatable.

So I need a method:

```
static string GetStableHashcode <T> (T object) where T: IStructuralEquatable
```

The .Net framework provide this type of function?
Otherwise, which algorithm to use?

Comment: Your question confuses me somewhat. Normally a hash codes do not vary over time and they are integers, not strings. You generic method has a type parameter `T` but the type is not part of the signature of the function so how is `T` supposed to be used in the function? Anyway, you can use .NET tuples or anonymous types to create hash codes by combining values but I am not sure this answers your question.

Comment: Yes the function can return an integer (so I have just to serialize it if I need a string). The `Object.GetHashCode` (on Tuple or any other .Net class) aren't stable. 2 execution instance (so 2 AppDomain) will produce 2 different hashcode for a same object!?!

Answer (score 0):

Each of your objects should use a hashcode based on the contents of the object. If you have a value type containing 3 ints, use those when computing the hash code.

Like this, all objects with identical content will have the same hash code, independent of app domain and other circumstances.

An example for a good hash code can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/1591992).

Comment: This is not a generic solution. Objects are not _my objects_. Those are just objects that implements `IStructuralEquatable`

Comment: But the contract for structural equatable requires that all objects that have the same content values are equal. If those objects do not contain equality/hashcode methods that satisfy that contract, you will have to wrap them and provide correct implementations for those methods yourself in the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use generics in your function so your question is how to implement the method

```
static string GetStableHashcode(IStructuralEquatable obj) { ... }
```

And the only sensible solution is to implement it like this:

```
static string GetStableHashcode(IStructuralEquatable obj) {
  return obj.GetHashCode().ToString();
}
```

Your concern is that [`Object.GetHashCode()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) does not provide values that are stable and the concern is very valid as can be seen in the first box headed by **Caution** in the documentation:

> - Do not serialize hash code values or store them in databases.
> - [...]
> - Do not send hash codes across application domains or processes. In some cases, hash codes may be computed on a per-process or per-application domain basis.

Actually, some hash codes created by `Object.GetHashCode` are stable like `Int32.GetHashCode` and `String.GetHashCode` and the algorithm used by `Tuple.GetHashCode` will also combine hash codes in a "stable manner". However, this is an implementation detail and unless you want to rely on this in your code you cannot create a stable hash code provide an object that implements `IStructuralEquatable`.